# Lua/C++ - Segfault inside lua_next() while trying to walk table

Tags: c++, lua, segmentation-fault

I have the following code in C++:

```
lua_getglobal(C, "theTable");
lua_pushnil(C);
while (lua_next(C, -2) != 0) {
  /* snip */
}
```

However, when it runs, a segfault is reported. The LLDB stop message is as follows.

```
* thread #1: tid = 0x50663f, 0x000000000002b36a luaos`luaH_next + 58, queue =
'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x38)
frame #0: 0x000000000002b36a luaos`luaH_next + 58
```

Luaos is the executable name. I have Lua compiled directly into the executable, for portability.

P.S. `C` is the name of the lua state. It is my secondary configuration lua state (as opposed to my primary code lua state `L`), which is the reason behind the name.

Comment: What are you doing in your loop? Are you adding elements to the stack and not cleaning them up? Are you altering the table you are walking over?

Comment: Each time through the loop, I push a few elements onto the stack, but I clean them up afterwards. I'm also 95% sure the problem is in the first iteration of the loop.

Comment: Do you leave the key on the stack at the end or are you cleaning that up by accident also? Does the crash happen if you use a positive index for the table?

Comment: I don't get to the point where accidentally deleting the key would matter. And yes, it happens if I use a positive index.

Comment: Are you using `lua_tostring` in the loop? This can confuse `lua_next` as mentioned in the manual.

Comment: Uh, yes? But again: THE PROBLEM IS IN THE FIRST ITERATION.

Comment: Do you load any C modules compiled as DLL? Maybe you link to multiple Lua runtimes ...

Comment: By "the first iteration" do you mean that your loop contents *never* happen at all?

Comment: @siffiejoe No, I'm running OS X, and I'm compiling lua directly into the executable.

Comment: @EtanReisner Yes. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: Do you have `lua_next` working anywhere else? Are other lua api functions working correctly? This sounds like a compilation or linking problem (or something deeper even perhaps).

Comment: I don;t use lua_next anywhere else, and other lua API functions work perfectly well.

Comment: Can you assert that the luavalue you got back from getglobal really is a table? eg. `luaL_checktype(C, -2, LUA_TTABLE);` or `assert( lua_istable(C, -2) );`.  Did you also try an empty loop, eg. `while (lua_next(C, -2) != 0) { lua_pop(C, 1); }` and that still segfault?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that your code is only partially correct, I'm going to explain how to use `lua_next` in details, even the parts that your code is doing correctly.
`lua_next` expects at least two elements in stack (in the following order):

```
[1] previous key
...
[t] table
```

In the first call to the function `previous key` should be `nil` so the function will push the first pair key-value to the stack, and the traversal will begin.

```
lua_getglobal(L, "theTable"); // Stack table
// ...
lua_pushnil(L);               // Push nil
lua_next(L, t);               // t is theTable index
```

When called `lua_next` pops the previous key and pushes a key-value pair to the stack, so it'll look something like this:

```
[1] value
[2] key
...
[t] -- unknown value --
[t+1] table
```

If the function is called again with this stack it'll have as inputs `value` as the current key and an unknown value as the `table`, thus an error will ocurr. To avoid that the top of the stack (`[1] value`) should be popped

```
lua_pop(L, 1); // Pop value
```

Now the stack will have the expected values for the traversal to continue, and `lua_next` can be called again.
When there are no more elements in the table the function will return 0.
Here is a complete example:

```
lua_getglobal(L, "theTable"); // Stack table
lua_pushnil(L);               // Push nil
while(lua_next(L, -2) != 0) {
    // Do something with key, value pair
    lua_pop(L, 1); // Pop value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see three potential problems:

- The global variable `theTable` does not exist and there is nil at position `-2`.
- You use `lua_tostring` inside the loop to convert keys to strings, perhaps for printing. The manual [says](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_next) that this confuses `lua_next`.
- You have some other value at position `-2` after the first loop iteration. Note that `lua_next` pushes two values onto the stack, the key and the value. You need to leave the key on top of the stack before calling `lua_next` again. And you need to make sure that the table remains at position `-2`. Perhaps it's safer to convert `-2` to an absolute position with `lua_gettop` after `lua_getglobal`. But you still need to leave the key returned by `lua_next` on top of the stack after each iteration.